# How to monitor what another user is typing in Linux

Tags: linux

If I am root, and I'd like to know what other people who have log on to the same system are typing in their terminal. How can I do that?

Comment: Several ways to do this. You might try [ttylog](https://metacpan.org/release/BBB/ttylog-0.83/view/ttylog) as an easy solution.

Answer (score 2):

> typing in their terminal

To backdoor all terminals, you'd need to modify the `ptty` driver of Linux, or use your kernel's tracing abilities to observe every TTY-related syscall made from software your user runs. You can, you're root, but that's changing a pretty central part of the operating system.

Also, if the thing they're interacting with is *not* a pseudo-terminal, then that doesn't help and you'd need to modify the way they interact with your system (e.g. by modifying `sshd`).

> If I am root, and I'd like to know what other people who have log on to the same system are typing in their terminal.

Not your business as root, by the way, in many cases. With big power comes big responsibility to protect and respect the privacy of your users. There's certainly legitimate cases (remote support, criminal investigations) where that might be useful to know, but in general, spying on legitimate users is amoral.

Comment: Spying may be immoral but it has been made explicitly clear by my employer that I have absolutely no right to privacy while I'm using their equipment or network. Example: ssl traffic is routinely decrypted at the firewall and examined for confidential content.

Comment: that's why I used "immoral", not "illegal", "forbidden".